# Git rm cached remove local file on local repo

Tags: git, gitignore

Hi i have a bare repo and 2 user got  clone from  that repo ,

after a while i founded that i need to ignore tracking images from a folder but we want to every client have that folder for themselves and not remove, [like storing product images]

so i add the folder to gitignore and then we need only bare repo to not have any images ,

so i searched and founded to remove pictures that before added we should use

```
git rm --cached folder/
```

so after using this command the client that used this command have that folder and every thing is ok

but another client run  `git pull` and see the local folder removed !

so what should we do that pictures only remove from bare repo, not clients that use git pull

Answer (score 1):

for example you can do: git rm -r --cached folder

Answer (score 0):

I think what happened is that the first client used `git rm` on the folders, then pushed, removing them from the branch on the repository.  Then, when another client pulled, Git effectively sent a delete order to those image files, thereby removing them from the second client's local files.

To avoid this happening for other clients, each client should first add the image files to `.gitignore` *before* pulling.  This way, when Git sends an order during the pull to delete the files, the files will be ignored and they will remain locally.

Comment: the folder was in .gitignore before pulled from bare repo but folder removed !

Comment: _You_ had the folder added to `.gitignore`, but did the client who lost the folder also have that?

Comment: yes i checked it  cause before this step .gitignore pushed on repo and other clients pulled it

Comment: Something is strange here, Git should be completely ignoring those files now.

Comment: you mean maybe problem in .gitignore file?

Comment: i tested it with another folder but folder removed 
for example i added this line to gitignore 'public/test/' then pushed it to remote repo another client git pull and updated gitignore file so it has updated gitignore after that we use git --rm cached and pusehd it to repo but another client see folder removed!!

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, create the `folder/` and add a file called `empty`, as git needs a file in a folder structure for it to exist.

In your .gitignore file, you'll have the ignore line `folder`. Right below that add a new line `!folder/empty` which will then mean ignore items in 'folder', but not the 'empty' file.

The same can be done with a blank index.html file or similar.

Comment: `.gitkeep` is a pretty standard name for the "empty" directory placeholder.

Comment: I've seen it done various different ways in various different projects.  I've seen it as `index.html` for web projects in case Apache has Indexes on (to stop directory listings); empty for some other projects, including web ones;  .keep as documented in https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/add-empty-folder-to-version-control  Basically there doesn't seem to be a standard way of doing it, unless I missed some documentation.  I'm happy to be pointed to more documentation on this though